# Change state in redux store depending on route

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to dispatch to store depending on which path I'm in, but it always run through the whole switch statement and dispatch the last case: (in my app.js).

```
const location = useLocation();
const dis = useDispatch();
 switch(location.path){
case "/":
  dis(nextStep(0))
case "/Payment-method":
  dis(nextStep(1))
  case "/Confirm":
    dis(nextStep(2))
default: console.log("error")
}
```

No matter under which conditions, I get that the state is always 2.
As shown in redux:
[image]

Each NEXT_STEP is in this order: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2 - which in turn leaves the state (stepUpdate) at 2.

The reason I want to do this is to keep track of which page number I'm in. This value in turn will be used in my stepper - which takes an integer value.

Comment: Try to use break at the end of each case or use return like `return dis(nextStep(0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try first with if else statement, this help to figure out the source of the problem
Or try to add **Break;** at the end of each case

Comment: thanks, just me forgetting how a switch statement works..